# exporting tikz pictures starting with 1 rather than 0

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters, tikz-external

I want to export my figures for an editor for import in another text editing program. I would like to have the name of the file correspond to the figures in the document. In the document they start with one but the export functionality of pgf adds a 0. The documentation says:

> Changes the names of all following figures. It is possible to change figure name during the document either using \tikzset{external/figure name={⟨name⟩}} or with this command. A unique counter will be used for each different {⟨name⟩}, and each counter will start at 0.

I tried to define the picture name and increase the counter, but the counter seems to have a different name:

```
\tikzsetfigurename{mueller-abbildung-}
\addtocounter{mueller-abbildung-}{1}
```

LaTeX complains:

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'mueller-abbildung-' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.131 ...nter{mueller-abbildung-}{1}
```

Comment: There is no counter. The value is stored in a macro. But without a minimal example it is not possible to test if, how and where one could change the start value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a real TeX counter. It holds the value and uses the `\tikzexternal@getnextfilename@advancecount` macro to step up. So it's normal that you can't find it.

Adding in the last part of the preamble the following

```
\expandafter\gdef\csname c@tikzext@no@\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/external/figure name}\endcsname{1}%
```

should solve it (untested in the absence of a MWE).